# Execute function according to time

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a way for every minute the execute_func function to be executed.

I have tried to loop in minutes, however the function is never executed, below the function

```
void main(void) {
    time_t timer;
    struct tm* tmr;

    timer = time(NULL);
    tmr = localtime(&timer);

        if (tmr->tm_min == 1)
            execute_func();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: you're calling back `main` from your function?? in an active CPU-loop to test the values from 0 to 59 ? that's weird. Hint: which function calls your `execute_func`? that will be the `main`, so you're calling `main` recursively without a base case...

Comment: It would be more usual to have the timing in `main` to call another function.

Comment: `tmr->tm_min` is within 0 and 59 so why looping?

Comment: I put main just as an example, I'm going to change.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, not a fantasy of your code.

Comment: All the code works, the only part that is not working is the execution time.

Comment: Use any sleep function to delay some time. For example `usleep` from <unistd.h>.

Comment: You fill in the `tmr` structure once with `localtime()`, but then inside the loop you simply compare `tm_min` with all the numbers from 0 to 59, one of which will always succeed. And this takes no time at all, so you'll just be calling the function constantly. You need to actually *wait*. Something like `sleep(60)`, for example.

Comment: The sleep it to for a certain time after it continues with the reading and finalizes I need something that performs the function 24 hours a day every 1 min

Comment: Call `localtime` until the minute changes from the previous call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a linux system, a system call will do it just fine. Here is an example of executing a piece of code or calling a function after every one minute:

```
while(true) 
    {
      system("sleep 60s"); 
      computeAFunction(); /* The function that you want to execute after every one minute */

       if( (true ) /* some code that you want to execute */
       {
         exit(0); /* if true exit */

                 }
       else
         {
            continue; /* or else keep running */
               }

      }
```

I have personally used this, when i wanted to keep computing a specif value which was changing with the passage of time, so i had to make decisions on the newly computed value.
You can modify it  a bit in a way which suits your needs.

Alternatively you can use the sleep() function defined in windows.h header file on windows sytems, and in unistd.h on linux.

sleep(1000) is equal to sleep 1s.

Answer (score 0):

How about your startup routine?
I mean your main function invokes execute_func, and function execute_func invokes main again. That's so strange.

If you just wanna do some periodic job. You can put these job into another no-main function. And you can use any delay function at the same time.

```
void PeriodicJob()
{
  xxx;
}

main()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    Sleep(60000); // You can use this function on windows platform. Notice that you must include windows.h first.
    // Or you can write your own delay function too.
    PeriodicJob();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to periodic run a program. That's your operating system's job. Try to use task schedule on your OS.