# I want to create C program that executes two threads at 10ms and 20ms periodically?

Tags: c, multithreading, timer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *t1(){
    long tid=9;
    printf("thread ID %ld",tid);
}
void *t2(){
    long tid=10;
    printf("thread ID %ld",tid);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1,thread2;
    int rc;
    int i=0;
    rc =pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,t1,NULL);
    if(rc)
        {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit();
        }
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,t2,NULL);
    return 0;

}
```

This is where I am at, I have created the threads and executed it but I don't know how to call those functions based on a timer.

Comment: Hii, Are you looking for something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148664/execute-function-according-to-time

Comment: No i need to use itimerspec in C

Comment: It's not clear whether you really want to create new threads periodically or whether you want to create the threads once and then have them print periodically. In either case can you just use [nanosleep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html)?

Comment: Checkout this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157209/is-there-an-alternative-sleep-function-in-c-to-milliseconds

Comment: I have to ask - why are you continually creating threads on a timer instead of just creating two threads that loop with an appropriate sleep call??